# Difference of power set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

For a set $X$, let $n(X)$ denote the cardinality of $X$ and $P(X)$ denote the power set of a set $X$. If there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that $n(P(A))−n(P(B))=240$, find $n(X)$ and $n(Y)$.

> $2^m-2^n=240$.

How to solve this equation to get the value of $m$ and $n$.
I do not think there is any positive $m$ and $n$ integers that would satisfy, given $2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512$, none of which has a difference $240$ and beyond $512$, the exponents of $2$ should not go as difference then exceeds $240$.

Seeking opinion if I am correct or missing something.

Comment: n=4, m=8. First $240=15\cdot 2^4$, so the minimum of m and n has to be 4 and then do some factoring, you get m=8

Comment: @JayceeZhang Is there any defined way to solve such equations?

Comment: I think you can use unique factorization of the intergers. $2^x-2^y=240>0$ so $x>y$, then $2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5=240=2^y(2^{x-y}-1)$ and $2^k-1$ is odd so we have $2^{x-y}-1=15$ and you have $x-y=4$ and $y=4 $ so you have $x=8$

Comment: These are integers. Factoring both $240$, and a $2^y$ from the left hand side, you get $2^y(2^{x-y}-1) = 240 = 2^4\times 3\times 5$. So $2^y=2^4$ and $2^{x-y}-1 = 15$, by unique factorization.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, as I thought initially MathJax might not be needed for the problem.

Comment: $240 = 256-16 = 2^8 - 2^4$.

Comment: It's never required for a problem, it's required for good typesetting and known symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Let us write $240$ in binary. As $240 = 128 + 64 + 32 + 16$, the binary expansion of $240$ is $11110000$. Now, the binary expansion of $2^k$ is $1\underbrace{00 \dotsm 0}_{\text{$k$ times}}$. Thus the equation $240 + 2^n = 2^m$ becomes in binary
$$
11110000 + 1\underbrace{00 \dotsm 0}_{\text{$n$ times}} = 1\underbrace{00 \dotsm 0}_{\text{$m$ times}}
$$
which immediately forces $n = 4$ and $m = 8$. More generally, the equation $2^m - 2^n = k$ has a solution if and only if the binary expansion of $k$ is a sequence of consecutive $1$ followed by a (possibly empty) sequence of $0$.